# Unable to assign $desktop_url and $marketing_title via C# in Branch.io

Tags: c#, json, rest, deep-linking, branch.io

I am replicating the branch.io request into C# for an API and trying to create URL by serializing them again via NewtonSoft. I've replicated the main part of the URL creation request well and it does generate a URL. But I have a problem when I tried to define my desktop_url and marketing_title within the query.

```
{"type":2, "branch_key":"key_test_lerbZ22zyjfpfFtl2auzukafywi220dN", "campaign":"new_product_annoucement", "channel":"email", "tags":["monday", "test123"], "data":"{\"name\": \"Alex\", \"email\": \"alex@branch.io\", \"user_id\": \"12346\", \"$desktop_url\": \"https://www.google.com\",\"$marketing_title\": \"This is Awesome\"}"}
```

As you can see from the JSON query, the desktop URL and marketing title both have a $ sign at the front i.e $desktop_url and $marketing_title.

I think that is the problem that inhibits me to create the replica in C#.I know the query is correct as if you run it now, it will definitely link to Google's Search Page.

My C# code is as follows:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public string GetWithBody([FromBody] getInfo info)
    {
        String mesh = info.affCode + "=========>" + info.appType;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new branchIOinfo()
            {
                type = 2,
                branch_key = "key_test_lerbZ22zyjfpfFtl2auzukafywi220dN",
                campaign = info.appType,
                alias = info.affCode,
                data = new BranchRequestData
                {
                    desktop_url = "https://www.google.com/"
                }
            };

            var response = client.PostAsync("https://api.branch.io/v1/url",
                new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(),
                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
                    response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    .Result);

                return content.url;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error Creating URL";
            }
```

My C# Model is as follows:

```
namespace BranchIOAPI.Models
{
  public class getInfo
  {
     public string affCode { get; set; }
     public string appType { get; set; }
  }

public class branchIOinfo
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string branch_key { get; set; }
    public string campaign { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public BranchRequestData data { get; set; }

}

public class BranchRequestData
{
    public string desktop_url { get; set; }
}
}
```

How am I to replicate that $ sign in this code or what is the correct way to replicate that JSON query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this mentions Branch, the question is really about how to change property names during serialization when using  C#.

I believe the appropriate approach here would be to use the JsonPropertyAttribute: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

So in the class definition you would do something like this:

```
public class BranchRequestData
{
    [JsonProperty("$desktop_url")]
    public string desktop_url { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch here:

The parameters with `$` at the beginning are simply a legacy convention in our system. You can specify these just like any other parameter, so unless there is something special about C# that I am forgetting, simply using `$desktop_url` and `$marketing_url` as the keys inside the `data` object should work fine.

Comment: Hey Alex, the problem C# does not actually recognise $ as a character that can be attached to the JSONString. It will return an error as this prefix is not recognised. Thus it has to be done like dwestgate said it.

     public class BranchRequestData
    {
         [JsonProperty("$desktop_url")]
         public string desktop_url { get; set; }
     }